# how to determine which class the item belongs to from onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, database, object, contextmenu, expandablelistview

I have an expandListView **diaryDisplaylist**

this is adapter **DiaryExpandListAdapter mAdapterForAll** which will be used to fill the diaryDisplayList

code snippet which does this:

```
    mAdapterForAll = new DiaryExpandListAdapter(this, diaryList);
    diaryDisplaylist.setAdapter(mAdapterForAll);
```

diarylist is of type:

```
    diaryList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

diaryList will have all items from about 8 databases from which expandlist is grouped according to date of the time of entry present in the database.
It displays it perfectly.

Now i have expandlist full of elements belonging to different databases.

So for edit and delete functionality i have used

```
    diaryDisplaylist.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
```

code snippet for contextMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {

        menu.add(0, Constants.MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, Constants.MENU_DELETE, 1, "Delete");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case Constants.MENU_EDIT:
        // once i get item belonging to respective database i can edit
        return true;

    case Constants.MENU_DELETE:

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In on contextMenuItem selected how can i find which database that item belongs to?
I cannot use adapter to find me the object because i dont have groupPosition and childPosition in contextItemSelected.
If i could get those i could have simply used.

```
Object selectedObject = mAdapterForAll.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
```

then using selectedObject i could have found out

```
if(selectedObject isInstanceOf db1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the above code was buggy this code works fine for me to determine the group and child position from expandlist view

```
int groupPos = 0, childPos = 0;
int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
    groupPos = ExpandableListView
            .getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    childPos = ExpandableListView
            .getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get group and child position i used

```
Object obj = diaryList.get((int) info.packedPosition);
```

in onContextItemSelected it worked.

Comment: Sorry the above code was buggy this code works fine for me to determine the group and child position from expandlist view